# Set and get data from vx_image

Tags: openvx

I have two `vx_image`'s `src` and `dst`, I need to get each pixel from the `src` `vx_image` and do some operation and set that to `dst` vx image.

```
vx_image src;
vx_image dst;
```

I couldn't find the proper documentation for doing this. May I know how to do this ?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a section "Host Memory Data Object Access Patterns" in the specification : https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenVX/specs/1.2/html/page_design.html#sec_host_memory

It shows examples of accessing different data objects (includeing images).

Comment: I have added the code in below answer, is it correct ?

Comment: There are two issues with provided code:
1) missing vxCommitImagePatch call
2) ignoring strides from vx_imagepatch_addressing_t

Comment: Do I need to have `vxCommitImagePatch()`, since I am copying data to `ptr2` which is data pointer of `vxDstImg`

Comment: Yes, each access should be followed by commit.

Answer (score 2):

```
 foo (vx_image & vxSrcImg, vx_image vxDstImg)
 {
        vx_rectangle_t rect1;
        vx_rectangle_t rect2;

        vxGetValidRegionImage(vxSrcImg, &rect1);
        vxGetValidRegionImage(vxDstImg, &rect2);

        vx_imagepatch_addressing_t addr1;
        vx_imagepatch_addressing_t addr2;

        vx_uint8 *ptr1 = NULL;
        vx_uint8 *ptr2 = NULL;
        vx_uint32  plane1;
        vx_uint32  plane2;

        vx_status status1 = vxAccessImagePatch(vxSrcImg, &rect1, plane1, &addr1, &ptr1, VX_READ_AND_WRITE);
        vx_status status2 = vxAccessImagePatch(vxDstImg, &rect2, plane2, &addr2, &ptr2, VX_READ_AND_WRITE);


        int i=0; 
        for (i = 0; i < addr1.dim_x * addr1.dim_y; i++)
        { 
          ptr2[i] = myPixelOperation (ptr1[i]);
        }

        // Rectangle needs to be commit back to the image post operation.
        vx_status status3 = vxCommitImagePatch(vxSrcImg, &rect1, plane1, &addr1, &ptr1);
        vx_status status4 = vxCommitImagePatch(vxDstImg, &rect2, plane2, &addr2, &ptr2);
  }
```